# how to show non-differentiability of function of two variables

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am currently reading Multivariate Calculus by Larson and Edwards. I understand the definition of differentiability of $z=f(x,y)$: if $\Delta z$ can be written as
$$\Delta z = f_x\Delta x + f_y\Delta y + e_1 \Delta x + e_2\Delta y$$
with $e_1,e_2 \rightarrow 0 $ as $\Delta x, \Delta y \rightarrow 0.$
Please explain what does this say geometrically. Also with this definition how to show a function is NOT differentiable.

Answer (score 0):

Geometrically this means that the surface $z=f(x,y)$ can be well approximated by its tangent plane (the error is of the second order).

The function is not differentiable when it is not possible to put it into that form. Try with $\dfrac{xy}{x^2+y^2}$ (which is $\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta)$) in polar coordinates).

Answer (score 0):

Geometrically this says that in the vicinity of point $(x,y)$ surface $z$ is **almost** same as tangent plane to surface at point $(x,y)$. You can understand more clearly by setting an analogy to case of functions of single variables. In the case of functions of single variables, we know that curve and tangent line become **almost** same in the vicinity of point where tangent touches the curve. Many texts say this statement by writing "secant approaches tangent as $\triangle x \to 0.$" In the vicinity of point there is **almost** no difference between secant and the curve.

For your second question you can calculate 
$$L=\lim_{(h,k)\to (0,0)}\dfrac{f(x+h,y+k)-f(x,y)-hf_x(x,y)-kf_y(x,y)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$$
which have been derived from the definition you have written in the question by transposition of first two terms to left hand side and replacing $\triangle x$ and $\triangle y$ by $h$ and $k$ respectively. Now if $L=0$ then the function is differentiable and **not differentiable otherwise**.